# get numeric ASCII value for a character

Tags: text-processing, scripting, od

I'm trying to write a shell script which asks for an ASCII character in the range A-Z or a-z and returns its equivalent numerical value. For example, the output might look like the following:

```
scarlet$ Please type a character between A and Z or between a and z:
scarlet$ A       
scarlet$ The decimal value of A is: 65
```

---

My attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Enter a letter:
read A
echo -n ${A} | od -i | head -1 | cut -b 10- | tr -d " "
```

Comment: I edited out your second question since it was unrelated; you should [post it separately](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) (you can get the original text [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/cb4d5704-7ac2-41a9-92ed-2578e8b0d8f9/view-source))

Comment: Your example works for me.  Can you paste output showing what happens and describe what the error is?  Does `echo -n A` do what you expect?  If not, try `printf` instead.  Does `od -i` do what you expect?  If not, try `od -t d1`.

Comment: I tried od -t d1 worked great... Thanks

Answer (score 13):

POSIX:

```
$ printf %d\\n \'a
97
```

It also works with non-ASCII characters in bash 4.0 and later and in zsh:

```
$ printf %x\\n \'あ
3042
```

You can also use `recode ..dump` to see hexadecimal code points:

```
$ printf aあ|recode ..dump
UCS2   Mne   Description

0061   a     latin small letter a
3042   a5    hiragana letter a
```

Comment: To make it a little bit less "obscure", one may also use e.g. `A=a ; printf '%d\n' "'$A'"` and on ksh something like `A=a; integer N=$(("'$A'")); print $N` (print or printf is not needed).

Answer (score 11):

POSIX: `printf a | od -A n -t d1`

Perl: `perl -e 'print ord($ARGV[0])' a`

Perl, coping with UTF-8 if in a UTF-8 locale: `perl -C255 -e 'print ord($ARGV[0])' œ`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter a letter:"
read A
echo ${A}|od -t d1|awk '{printf "%s",$2}';echo
```

Cheers

Comment: I would just use awk, rather than nawk. This is pretty standard to any awk version.

Comment: Edited, is my habit of using 'nawk' since i've not awk at work

Comment: yes, your solution worked for me too .. thanks

Answer (score 1):

A od-less solution, just bash, and just lowercase, so far. `z` is the character searched for, here `s` as search. `i=97` because ascii(a)=97. The rest is obvious.

```
z=s 
i=97
for c in {a..z}
do 
    [ "$c" = "$z" ] && echo $i && break || ((i+=1))
done
```

You may put it into a single line of course. Here are some semmicolons: `;;;;;` (should be enough)

Comment: I tested the above code .. but it didn't work for me .. I got a message saying " i+=1 " is not found!

Comment: This works in bash. You may need i=$((i+1)) instead.

Comment: In one line and with reading a key from the keyboard: `read char; i=97; for c in {a..z}; do  [ "$c" = "$char" ] && echo $i && break || ((i+=1)); done`

Answer (score 0):

Try `od -t d1` if you have it.  The other output formats are quite weird.

You also don't need head and cut, for example:

```
printf "A" | od -t d1 | read addr num && echo $num
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Get one character per loop, until the user presses <Enter>
while true ; do 
    read -n 1 c
    (( ${#c} == 0 )) && break # Exit the loop. Input length is 0  
                              # ie. The user has pressed Enter
    #
    if [   \( ! "$c" \< "a" -a  ! "$c" \> "z" \) \
        -o \( ! "$c" \< "A" -a  ! "$c" \> "Z" \) ]
    then
        val=($(ascii -s $c)) # build an array of ascii info for this char 
        echo " ... The decimal value of $c is: ${val[1]}"
    else
        echo -n  $'\r \r' # overwrite the invalid character
    fi 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a program that does this and you're not doing this as an exercise then there's a program called `ascii` that does this. Your distro may offer it as a package already, if not get it from http://www.catb.org/~esr/ascii/.